# preprocessor LINE and FILE printf directives to print informative messages

Tags: c, file, c-preprocessor

I was asked to use the preprocessor LINE and FILE printf directives to print informative messages:

```
#define malloc( x ) mymalloc( x, __FILE__, __LINE__ ) 
#define free( x ) myfree( x, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
```

and I've read others' code like https://github.com/mtrajano/mymalloc/blob/master/mymalloc.c and  but I didn't see that *file is used in their function, so I'm wondering why is the purpose and function to use LINE and FILE?

Comment: So that you can know *which* call to `mymalloc()` was in error when debugging, without using a debugger.

Comment: `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are not `printf` directives.  They are automatically defined macros.  You may choose to use them in a `printf` call, but they are not specific to `printf`.  They can be used to provide debugging info.  Typically they are used when displaying an error message, to make it clear where the error originated.

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)